# Ngrok works only in LAN

Tags: linux, networking, localhost, http-proxy

guys. 
I'm sorry for my bad English. I have a problem with ngrok on my kali machine. The strange fact is that two days ago it worked properly. After typing: 
ngrok http 80
 A link is generated. But the link works only in LAN. Over WAN it says "tunnel xxxxx.ngrok.io not found". 
I did some tests. I’m trying creating a tunnel from my triple boot setup (kali,macOS Catalina hackintosh, Windows) and ngrok link works properly in WAN only in Windows. I tried even another PC with kali live and ngrok works properly. In conclusion I think that it couldn't be a WiFi problem. Any ideas? I'm using the last version of ngrok (2.3.35)

Comment: Kali is absolutely not for beginners. Start on a more complete unix, switch to kali when you already know what you're doing. Compulsory kali link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: I understand the fact that kali isn’t for beginners. But the problem is related to ngrok. Even if I start it on macOS (that is friendly-use) there is the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already found a solution than here is a one of the possible solutions that I found for the this issue. Note this is only if you are using Kali as a virtual machine in virtual box. I couldn't pinpoint the problem, but it seems like the issue is either with the bridge connection or Nat network connection. So just change it to host only adapter and when you boot up use a wifi adapter rather than the Ethernet connection that connect your virtual machine to your host machine. Just use ifconfig command and turn the wired connection off. That should do the trick.